# How to list all members of an object, and know which are inherited members

Tags: php

What is the best way to iterate all data members and functions of a class, also checking which of them are inherited.

Comment: [does this help?](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to do that. It appears you'll have to look at all the parents manually to get the inherited properties. Here's a [comment on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php#88405) that may be a good start

Copied the code in case the comment get taken down...

```
function getClassProperties($className, $types='public'){
    $ref = new ReflectionClass($className);
    $props = $ref->getProperties();
    $props_arr = array();
    foreach($props as $prop){
        $f = $prop->getName();

        if($prop->isPublic() and (stripos($types, 'public') === FALSE)) continue;
        if($prop->isPrivate() and (stripos($types, 'private') === FALSE)) continue;
        if($prop->isProtected() and (stripos($types, 'protected') === FALSE)) continue;
        if($prop->isStatic() and (stripos($types, 'static') === FALSE)) continue;

        $props_arr[$f] = $prop;
    }
    if($parentClass = $ref->getParentClass()){
        $parent_props_arr = getClassProperties($parentClass->getName());//RECURSION
        if(count($parent_props_arr) > 0)
            $props_arr = array_merge($parent_props_arr, $props_arr);
    }
    return $props_arr;
}
```

Comment: Seems that my problem is solved, but can you please explain what these if statements with continue keywords imply?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the reflection: http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

For example with this you can list all public and protected properties:

```
$foo = new Foo();

$reflect = new ReflectionClass($foo);
$props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);
var_dump($props);
```

You can use `ReflectionClass::getParentClass`to get the parent class and then compare the properties of your class with the properties of the parent class to see what was inherited.